# The jsonb field does not work correctly in QGIS

Tags: qgis, postgis, postgresql, sql

I created a trigger that should automatically populate the field, but for some reason in QGIS 3.16, the value is not displayed, only the key is populated.

[image]

The key shows
09132000-3.1.3
14210000-6.3.3
09132000-3.1.1
t20
t41,  but does not show the value.

Tell me how to set it up correctly?